# /proc/meminfo says VmallocUsed is 0. So where are my kernel modules stored?

Tags: linux-kernel, memory, kernel-modules

I thought the code for kernel modules was stored in a vmalloc() allocation?  (In fact I'm sure the [kernel code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.16/source/kernel/module.c#L2729) is using vmalloc(), not kvmalloc()).  So why does `/proc/meminfo` say I have no zero `VmallocUsed` ?

```
$ grep Vmalloc /proc/meminfo
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
$ lsmod|head
Module                  Size  Used by
vfio_mdev              16384  0
mdev                   20480  1 vfio_mdev
vfio_iommu_type1       28672  0
vfio                   32768  2 vfio_mdev,vfio_iommu_type1
kvm_intel             237568  0
kvm                   737280  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
dummy                  16384  0
binfmt_misc            20480  1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fields were zeroed in Linux 4.4, for performance reasons.  Programs linked against glibc read this file when they started up, and it was causing a measurable impact.

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/a5ad88ce8c7fae7ddc72ee49a11a75aa837788e0